# How to check On-Device mode translation in IOS15

Tags: swift, xcode, ios15

Is there a way to check with Swift if the On-Device mode is enabled in the translation function of IOS15?

If anyone know please tell me!!

[image]

Comment: Why would you need to know?

Comment: Because I want to introduce this translation feature into application which I developed for my company, but I don't want to send sensitive company information to Apple servers. I want to make app can use the translation function once the On-Device mode is enabled.